# How to know what is included in a Unity Asset Store asset

Tags: unity, assets

I'm very new to Unity and game development in general.

I'd like to re-create the [birch forest demo video shown here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vegetation/trees/birch-trees-package-633#content). I presume this isn't a scene that comes with your purchase, but just "what you could do"? It looks like you get assets and prefab to put in your own creations using something like Vegetation Studio / Vegetation Studio Pro?

I'd like to know how I can find out whether this scene is included in the asset, or if I'd have to build it myself from the bits and pieces that are included.

I'm emailing the asset seller too, but thought I'd check here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind! I see the scenes in the *Package Content* section of the Assets Store item page. Apologies for the noise.

[image]